Nextjs + Prisma - "TypeError: fetch failed" during build time | EDIT: Fixed
I'm attempting to generate static pages during build time in Nextjs (using /app routes) with Prisma.
Everything works while running a dev environment. However, attempting to build the app fails with the following error (which repeats for any place where I attempt to get data using prisma):
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12442:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async globalThis.fetch (/Users/alex/dev/wa/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:36091)
    at async i (/Users/alex/dev/wa/.next/server/app/acc/[instrument]/page.js:1:7501)
    at async g (/Users/alex/dev/wa/.next/server/app/acc/[instrument]/page.js:1:3645) {
  cause: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]: 
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]

The following is code in one of my server-side page components:
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const instruments = await getInstruments();

    return instruments.map((i) => ({
        instrument: i,
    }));
}

const Page = async ({params}) => {
     const info = await getInfo(params.instrument)
}

getInfo:
const getInfo = async (instrument) => {
   const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/instruments/${instrument}`)

if (!res.ok) { throw new Error('...') }

if(res.ok) { return await res.json() }
}

Fetch successfully gets to GET on the server, where I attempt to call
const info = await prisma.info.findMany({ where: { instrument }}).
When I console.log right before the prisma call, it logs successfully. however nothing I log after is shown. what follows the call is just the error above.
Again, this only happens after attempting to run:
npx prisma generate && npx prisma migrate deploy && next build.
My prisma .db setup:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

type PrismaClientSingleton = ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
  prisma: PrismaClientSingleton | undefined;
};

const prismaClient = globalForPrisma.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production")
  globalForPrisma.prisma = prismaClient;


NextConfig:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    typescript: {
        // !! WARN !!
        // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
        // your project has type errors.
        // !! WARN !!
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
};

**module.exports = nextConfig;**

Versions:
"next": "14.1.4"
"prisma": "^5.12.1",
"typescript": "5.4.4",

I should be able to successfully fetch data and populate server-side rendered components during build time.
EDIT:
The Fix: Instead of calling the getInfo function in generateStaticParams, which makes a fetch to my api endpoint, I need to call the prisma.info.findMany function directly.
I first assumed this is because the server isn't running during build time, but it confuses me that I can console.log from my server during build time. What am I misunderstanding?
